# Carbon PHP previousWeekday returns a weekend day

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon PHP to build a small API for my project. I need to get the last working day of the month, in my context, this should be the very last weekday of each month.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```php
$lastWorkingDay = Carbon::parse('2022-04-27')->lastOfMonth();

if ($lastWorkingDay->isWeekend()) {
    $lastWorkingDay = Carbon::parse('2022-04-27')->lastOfMonth()->previousWeekday();
}
```

The problem I've encountered here, is that in April, the last day of the month is on a weekend, so then my `previousWeekday` method appears to be getting the saturday rather than the friday?

Comment: This seems to work for me. Using your code, `$lastWorkingDay->englishDayOfWeek` is Friday. You can actually make it a bit easier by using `$lastWorkingDay->previousWeekday();` inside of your if block, which will modify the original object.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot easier if

```
$lastWorkingDayOfMonth = Carbon::parse('2022-04-27')
  ->modify('first Day of next Month')
  ->modify('last weekday');
```

is used. modify is a method that Carbon inherited from DateTime.

This is also possible without Carbon only with DateTime. Here's a [little test](https://3v4l.org/c4a1K).

If the code is required more often in an application, a macro can be defined for it in Carbon.

```
Carbon::macro('lastWorkingDayOfMonth', function() {
    return $this->modify('first Day of next Month')->modify('last weekday');
});
```

lastWorkingDayOfMonth() can now be used anywhere in Carbon like any other method.

```
echo Carbon::parse('2022-04-27')->lastWorkingDayOfMonth()->format('l, d F Y');
//Friday, 29 April 2022
```